# Get index of column containing string of key:value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame `df`:

```py
Name   Student_info                                                          School
Rajat  {"FirstName":"Rajat", "LastName":"Sinha", "birthDate":"1999-05-01"}   XYZ
Vivek  {"FirstName":"Vivek", "LastName":"Vishwa", "birthDate":"1999-07-09"}  ABC
Ram    {"FirstName":"", "LastName":"Ram", "birthDate":"1999-05-09"}          ABC
John   {"FirstName":"", "LastName":"Mac", "birthDate":"1999-08-03"}          ABC
```

I want to get the index of `FirstName` and `LastName` (indices of the keys and corresponding values). How can I get this? e.g: index of `"FirstName":"Rajat"` inside the `Student_info` column.

I tried:

```py
index = [i for i in df.columns if isinstance(data[i][0], dict)]
```

But this gives index as null (as it's not a dictionary, but a string of values in the form of `"key":"value"` pairs)

I want to check if `"FirstName":""` is empty:

```py
ValueToCheck = ""
ValuesInDataframe = ?  # get the index of empty string of key FirstName
```

```py
if (ValueToCheck == ValuesInDataframe):
    return true
```

What is the best way to get the index to compare the strings?

Comment: Your question is not very clear: What does _"index of `"FirstName":"Rajat"` inside the `Student_info` column"_ mean? Could you add the exact expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still a bit unclear. Does this solve your problem:

If the `Student_info` column contains strings instead of dictionaries then do this first:

```
df.Student_info = df.Student_info.map(eval)
```

Now you can use [`.str.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) to extract the indices for the rows that meet the requirement:

```
indices = df[df.Student_info.str.get('FirstName').eq('')].index
```

Result:

```
Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

So

```
df.loc[indices]
```

results in:

```
   Name                                       Student_info School
2   Ram  {'FirstName': '', 'LastName': 'Ram', 'birthDat...'   ABC
3  John  {'FirstName': '', 'LastName': 'Mac', 'birthDat...'   ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your df is being read from a csv (or similar) file, something along the lines of:

```
data = StringIO('''
Name     Student_info                                                       School
Rajat    {"FirstName":"Rajat","LastName":"Sinha","birthDate":"1999-05-01"}     XYZ
Vivek    {"FirstName":"Vivek","LastName":"Vishwa","birthDate":"1999-07-09"}    ABC
Ram      {"FirstName":"","LastName":"Ram","birthDate":"1999-05-09"}            ABC
John     {"FirstName":"","LastName":"Mac","birthDate":"1999-08-03"}            ABC
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s+')
```

In this case 'Student_info' has strings that 'look like' dicts.

We can convert them to actual dicts by `pply`-ing `eval` and then expanding into separate columns:

```
df_si = df['Student_info'].apply(eval).apply(pd.Series)
```

`df_si` looks like this:

```
    FirstName   LastName    birthDate
0   Rajat       Sinha       1999-05-01
1   Vivek       Vishwa      1999-07-09
2               Ram         1999-05-09
3               Mac         1999-08-03
```

You can combine this with the rest of df using `join`:

```
df = df[['Name', 'School']].join(df_si)
```

Now `df` looks like this:

```
    Name    School    FirstName    LastName    birthDate
--  ------  --------  -----------  ----------  -----------
 0  Rajat   XYZ       Rajat        Sinha       1999-05-01
 1  Vivek   ABC       Vivek        Vishwa      1999-07-09
 2  Ram     ABC                    Ram         1999-05-09
 3  John    ABC                    Mac         1999-08-03
```

You can now extract those rows where Firstname is an empty string:

```
df[df['FirstName']=='']
```

output:

```
    Name    School    FirstName    LastName    birthDate
--  ------  --------  -----------  ----------  -----------
 2  Ram     ABC                    Ram         1999-05-09
 3  John    ABC                    Mac         1999-08-03
```